# hardcoded string “Button”, should use @string resource

Tags: android-layout, android-activity

I am new in Android app development and using Java language. 
My problem is every time I make a TextView or Button there is a triangle with the exclamation mark below them.
and when I click it I saw a message saying:

> hardcoded string “Button”, should use @string resource

I have two activities, in my main activity there is a Button that when you click it you will go in second activity.
But when I go to my `main.java` to make a code for the button. There's always the above shown error. I think the eclipse can't find the id of my button and same for my TextView they have same error message.

Here is the code I made:

```
Button b = FindViewById(R.id.button1);
```

I also add:

```
Button b = (Button) FindViewById(R.id.button1);
```

I am using the latest eclipse classic and ADT august issue. The platform is Android 4.1 API 16.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't hardcode the "text" on the widgets use the strings resources ie., strings in the strings.xml to set the text. Declare the "text" you want to display as a string in strings.xml and access it using @string/your_string_name in the layout file.

Comment: like this one: <resources>
    <string name="button1">button</string>
</resources>

<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/button" />

Comment: just use button1 in place of button and things should be fine. Accept my answer and upvote it if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Main.xml file (The xml file which relates to the main activity)]

Notice the id of the button, which is rounded in red. You have to use this id when you want to call it in a method, for an example

```
Button b = (Button) FindViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Furthermore, check whether your graphical layout matches with the image I have provided.

[image: Graphical view of the Main.xml file]

Just try your code again with these changes.
Your main.java would look like this.

[image: Main.java file]

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie too, but I believe I got this. So basically what's happening here, java wants you to put your hardcodes in string.xml. so that when accessing it, you will use the given methods below before:

[image: Before].

But this is how it should be.
Let's start by string.xml

[image: create the same element like this in string.xml]

Then come back to your activity_main.xml

[image: Reference the created element this way]

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, make changes to the String.xml and activity_main.xml files.

In this example you must create a text string in the strings.xml file.
[strings.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mmlp.png)

And in the activity_main.xml file, you should find the text of the string created, as shown in the example image. Save everything and the error disappears.
[activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISqEA.png)